# Given 2D coordinates of persons in a list, how do I find people with the distance from each other is below a threshold?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have list of 3-tuples:

- name
- coordinate x
- coordinate y

A *jerk* is a person whose distance to any other person in a list is less than 2.

I think that my code works, but because of a nested loop its complexity is O(N²). Is it possible to make it more efficient?

```
people=[
  ('Mickey', 4.6, 3.2),
  ('Donald', 6.1, 3.2),
  ('Bambi',  6.2, 5.2),
  ('Goofy',  6.4, 2.0),
  ('Eeyore', 7.0, 6.4)]

min_distance_sq=2.**2

jerks=set()
for p1 in people:
    if p1 in jerks:
        continue
    for p2 in people:
        if p1[1]==p2[1]:
            continue
        distance_sq=(p1[2]-p2[2])**2+(p1[3]-p2[3])**2
        if distance_sq < min_distance_sq:
            jerks.add(p1)
            jerks.add(p2)
            break

for jerk in jerks:
    print(jerk[0],'from',jerk[1],'is jerk')
```

Comment: its look fine. try to add more people with diverse arguments so you be able to check your self

Answer (score 0):

Improvement can be achieved by:

1. [Caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Memoization) square calculations, thus calculating them only once.
2. Comparing looping on people comparison in such a way we only compare each person with another once. 
   This can be implemented by looping on all people, in the first loop, 
   and looping on the people to be measured with, in the second loop, by iterating over all people that are after the index of the current first-loop person.

```
people=[
  ('Mickey','1 High Street',4.6,3.2),
  ('Donald','1 High Street',6.1,3.2),
  ('Bambi','2 High Street',6.2,5.2),
  ('Goofy','3 High Street',6.4,2.0),
  ('Eeyore','2 High Street',7.0,6.4)]

squared_distance_dict = dict()

min_distance_radius=2.
min_distance_sq=min_distance_radius**2

squared_distance_dict[min_distance_radius] = min_distance_sq

jerks=set()
for p1 in people:
    for i, p1 in enumerate(people):
        for p2 in people[i+1:]:
        # Calculating distances
        x_diff = p1[2]-p2[2]
        y_diff = p1[3]-p2[3]
        # Getting squared results from cache dictionary, or calculating them if not present
        x_diff_sq = squared_distance_dict.get(x_diff, x_diff ** 2)
        y_diff_sq = squared_distance_dict.get(y_diff, y_diff ** 2)
        distance_sq=x_diff_sq+y_diff_sq
        if distance_sq < min_distance_sq:
            jerks.add(p1)
            jerks.add(p2)
            break

for jerk in jerks:
    print(jerk[0],'from',jerk[1],'is jerk')
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is that you are getting the distance between Bambi and Mickey, for example, again knowing that you already got the distance between Mickey and Bambi before (You are looping over all people again each time).

**How to Fix**

You have to loop only forward, I mean you compare Mickey with all the others, then you compare Donald with them all except Mickey and so on. So you are comparing:

```
'Mickey' with ['Donald', 'Bambi', 'Goofy', 'Eeyore']
'Donald' with ['Bambi', 'Goofy', 'Eeyore']
'Bambi' with ['Goofy', 'Eeyore']
'Goofy' with ['Eeyore']
'Eeyore' with []
```

So this is the code to do this:

```
people=[
  ('Mickey','1 High Street',4.6,3.2),
  ('Donald','1 High Street',6.1,3.2),
  ('Bambi','2 High Street',6.2,5.2),
  ('Goofy','3 High Street',6.4,2.0),
  ('Eeyore','2 High Street',7.0,6.4)]

min_distance_sq=2.**2

jerks=set()

for i, p1 in enumerate(people):
    if p1 not in jerks:
        for p2 in people[i+1:]:     # execlude p1 and the people before
            if p2[1] != p1[1]:
                distance_sq=(p1[2]-p2[2])**2+(p1[3]-p2[3])**2
                if distance_sq < min_distance_sq:
                    jerks.add(p1)
                    jerks.add(p2)
                    break

for jerk in jerks:
    print(jerk[0],'from',jerk[1],'is jerk')
```

Running the code gives me the output as follows:

```
Donald from 1 High Street is jerk
Bambi from 2 High Street is jerk
```

I don't know if that's what you want, if you could put your output it would be clearer.

**Update**
I updated the code not to compare people from same High street. The output is now the same as you got in your code. Thanks to @Stef 's comment

Comment: The two lines `if p1 in jerks: continue` prevent this from working as intended. Consider the input: `people=[('Mickey','1 High Street',0,0), ('Donald','1 High Street',0,1), ('Bambi','2 High Street',0,2), ('Goofy','3 High Street',0,4), ('Eeyore','2 High Street',0,6)]`. Your code returns only `Mickey` and `Donald` as jerks, even though `Bambi` is only 1 away from `Donald`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build some kind of binary space partition (BSP) data structure.

For example, [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) with building time O(nlogn) and make queries "Nearest neighbour" for every item